# sqlite3 not working; no root; UNIX; Python3.8.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, unix, jupyter

I installed Python3.8.11 w/o root access on an Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS system:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.11/Python-3.8.11.tgz
tar-xvzf Python-3.8.11.tgz
cd Python-3.8.11/
./configure --prefix=${PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR} --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && make install
```

Sqlite 3 fails with the following error:

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "${PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "${PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'


>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

I’ve seen similar issues advising to `sudo apt install sqlite-devel` and other packages, but since I don’t have (and won’t have) root access, it simply isn’t an option for me.
I’ve tried to install sqlite3 to a custom location:

```
wget https://sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-autoconf-3360000.tar.gz
tar -xvzf sqlite-autoconf-3360000.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3360000
./configure && make
SQLITE_INSTALL_DIR=$(pwd)
```

Add it to my path via ~/.bashrc

```
PATH="${PATH}:${SQLITE_INSTALL_DIR}" ; export PATH
```

Re install python: `./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && make install`
But I still get exactly the same error with sqlite3

What can I do?

I need to get sqlite3 working so I can run `jupyter lab` in my bash shell, which currently boils down to these two mistakes:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your imported from wrong path.

Try this:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it, I get the same issue:
>>> from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
(stuff happens)
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Also, I'm trying to run jupyter lab, which itself is trying to import sqlite3 the way I described above. If jupyter lab tries to import sqlite3 in a specific way, I think the program knows the best way to import sqlite3